# CakePHP Post action field filter

Tags: cakephp, post, filter, request

For security purposes, I'd like to filter all un-allowed fields from the `$this->request->data` Array.

E.g. my `$this->request->data` looks like this:

```
array(
    'User' => array(
        'password' => '*****',
        'email' => 'asd@asdasd.de'
    )
)
```

and I want to apply this Filter to the array above:

```
array(
    'User' => array(
        0 => 'password',
        1 => 'email'
    )
)
```

So all post-data's fields that are not in the filter-Array are being unset.

Comment: You don't have to do that - or in other words: doing that does not make your application any more or less secure. Just dont print it out or don't pass it on to the model (keyword: whitelisting). What exactly are you trying to accomplish here? Is there a specific use case?

Answer (score 0):

The only reason I can see where this would make sense is during your register/login actions where invalidation would result in the password being outputted again in some way.

There you just have to set it to empty before passing it down to the view again:

```
if ($this->Auth->login()) {
    // flash message
    return $this->redirect($this->Auth->redirectUrl());
}
$this->request->data['User']['password'] = '';
```

See https://github.com/dereuromark/cakefest/blob/master/Controller/AccountController.php#L26 for an example.

Answer (score 0):

Just use the [SecurityComponent](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/security-component.html) and you're done. It automatically verifies that the form is valid (using a hash) and prevents a few other attacks.

If there is a field that was injected into the form the Security component will black hole the request. [This section](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/security-component.html#form-tampering-prevention) of the book tells you how it works. Basically it's just add the component and you're done. But I really recommend to read the book about it to get an understanding of what it does to prevent attacks.